# Make A WordPress Page Accessible To Admins Only, Redirect Other User Roles

Tags: admin, redirect, user-roles, user-access

I need to redirect **logged-in** and **non-admin** users, from page with id 172, to the home of the website. Note that users that are not logged in can actually see the page.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'xyz');
function xyz() {
    if( is_page( 172 ) ) {
             if( is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can('update_core') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
             }
    }   
}
```

Problem: This code is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`admin_init` runs on admin pages, not the front end. The equivalent front end action, `init`, is too early to check `is_page`. A safe action for redirection is `template_redirect`:

```
function xyz() {
    if( is_page( 172 )
        && ! current_user_can('update_core') ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
            exit;
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'xyz' );
```